# Accessing instance property in initializer gives "Variable used before being initialized" in some situations

Tags: swift

Can anybody explain to me why this code compiles:

```swift
class MyClass {
  let a: Bool
  let b: Bool

  init(aa: Bool, bb: Bool) {
    self.a = aa
    if self.a {/*Do Stuff*/}
    self.b = bb
  }
}
```

But this code throws a compiler error

> Constant 'self.c' used before being initialized

at line `if self.a && self.b {/*Do Stuff*/}`:

```swift
class MyClass {
  let a: Bool
  let b: Bool
  let c: Bool

  init(aa: Bool, bb: Bool, cc: Bool) {
    self.a = aa
    self.b = bb
    if self.a && self.b {/*Do Stuff*/}
    self.c = cc
  }
}
```

I have some basic understanding of Swift's two-phase initialization (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH18-ID203) and I'm pretty sure this is the reason for the error, but from my understanding, shouldn't both snippets of code throw that same compiler error?

Comment: I should have pointed out, this is a minimized test case of an error from a more complicated piece of code. I realize that there are ways to get around the error, and I have already done so in my project. I'm just interested in a technical explanation as to why the top snippet is valid but the bottom is not. Just trying to get a better understanding of Swift.

Comment: Interesting question.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it has everything to do with two-phase initialization.  The issue in your second example is `&&`.

From the safety checks associated with this (and your link):

"An initializer cannot call any instance methods, read the values of any instance properties, or refer to self as a value until after the first phase of initialization is complete."

Modifying your first example and adding the && operator:

```
class MyClass {
      let a: Bool
      let b: Bool

      init(aa: Bool, bb: Bool) {
            self.a = aa
            if self.a && self.b {/*Do Stuff*/}
            self.b = bb
      }
}
//Playground execution failed: MyPlayground.playground:4:26: error: constant 'self.b' used before being initialized
            if self.a && self.b {/*Do Stuff*/}
```

Modifying your second example and removing the && operator:

```
class MyClass {
      let a: Bool
      let b: Bool
      let c: Bool

      init(aa: Bool, bb: Bool, cc: Bool) {
            self.a = aa
            self.b = bb
            if self.a  {/*Do Stuff*/}
            self.c = cc
      }
}

//it runs fine
```

Of course moving self.c before the line with the && operator completes the first phase of initialization along with safety checks.  But the safety check fails if you attempt to perform operations prior to initializing all properties.  You also will be limited to what you can do within the `if self.a {/*Do Stuff*/}` closure.

Comment: That's the safety check I was thinking, but does that wording not lead you to believe that the first snippet should fail as well? It's absolutely "read[ing] the values of any instance properties". When you say "limited to what you can do", is there any formal definition of what that limitation is? Like what is it about being on the right hand side of the && operator that breaks the rule but being on the left hand side is fine?

Comment: it could be worded better but "read the values of any instance properties" is the key piece.  You can assign a default value, but to perform calculations you need to initialize all properties first.    You will find these issues in other areas of the documentation.  Have fun!